# Messages in iOS 8 Details displaying broken images, all images gone

Tags: messages, ios

Suddenly (as in, not associated with the actual update or any actual trigger that I know of), my iPhone stopped displaying any images that were associated with previous messages. All I see now are filenames and broken images, as shown in the image below.

This is infuriating.

Some things to note:

- I have tried a restart of the phone, and no difference.
- I also turned off and back on iMessage on this device, also no change.
- The images do display on my Mac and iPad. I made a smart folder on my Mac to get all images and photos under this location, and copied them out to be safe.
- Those I have shared images with still see theirs.
- Messages in Settings - General - Usage - Manage says Messages is only using 8MB, which would be really odd.

UPDATE: updated that these images do exist on other devices/machines, so it just appears that my phone lost its mind. I backed up everything just to be safe. Unsure if I should wipe my device (new one comes very soon), or not.

[image: screenshot of missing images]

Comment: If it says Messages is only using 8MB, and you have sent or received more than a few photos/videos, the photos and videos were likely erased somehow. They should exist in a backup, though you will lose any data since your last backup if you restore.

Comment: Exactly, although I have no idea why they got erased. Phone had plenty of space, etc.